# Excel - convert part of filename to mm/dd/yy date

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a spreadsheet that has the filename 05-20-14-transactions.xml ... how can I display the date in a style such as "5/20/14" or "May 20, 2014" in a field within that spreadsheet? Can a formula read and 'understand' the spreadsheet's own filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula to extract the current file name is:

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))-1)
```

You can have Excel auto-parse the first 8 characters as a date with `DATEVALUE()`, resulting in:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(=MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))-1),8))
```

Format this as a date, and you're all set.